# How to drop some characters with Regex in vs?

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I have a sql table and I have a column which includes data  such as: B757-34-11-00-I-1, A300-223100-0503-1 etc.

A300-223100-0503-1 -> 223100-0503-1 
 B757-34-11-00-I-1 -> 34-11-00-I-1

How  can i do that with regex? I need two kinds of solutions: sql and C#. how can I do that with sql query in SQL and C#

i need drop charater as far as "-" may be dropping more than 5 characters or less than? i need also drop  "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL:

```
SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%-%', col) + 1)
```

in C#:

```
val.Substring(val.IndexOf('-') + 1)
```

This requirement is so simple, there is no need for regexes (and SQL Server does not natively support them anyway if you do not add this via a stored procedure implemented in .net).

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression is overkill for simple string manipulation like this.

C#:

```
value.Substring(value.indexOf('-') + 1)
```

SQL:

```
substring(field, charindex('-', field) + 1, 1000)
```

(The last parameter could be calculated as `len(field) - charindex('-', field) - 1`, but you can just use a value that you know is larger than the max length.)

Answer (score 1):

Is it *always* just dropping the first 5 characters? If so, you don't need to use a regex at all.

C#:

```
value = value.Substring(5);
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field, 5, LEN(field) - 5)
```

Comment: i need drop charater as far as "-" may be dropping more than 5 characters or less than? i need also drop  "-"

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "A300-223100-0503-1";
Regex rgx = new Regex("^[^-]+-(.*)$");
string result = rgx.Replace(input, "$1");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Was the down voted for using regex instead of substring or for not including the sql version?